# Do any languages greatly restrict the placement of adjectives/adverbs in a phrase or sentence?

Tags: cross-linguistic, adjectives, adverbs

I am working on a conlang and wondering how natural languages might limit the placement of "modifiers" (adjectives and adverbs) in a sentence.

For example:

> 1. I **eventually** walked to the store.
> 2. I walked to the store **eventually**.

Those basically mean the same thing, but `eventually` is placed in different spots: (1) has it preceding the main verb, (2) has it completely separate from and after the verb. You could even have a 3rd rendition: "I walked eventually to the store", but that feels a little more contrived/unnatural to me.

Do any languages make a rule saying something like "all adverbs must directly precede the verb, no separation", and/or "all adjectives must precede the noun, no separation"?

With the following, the first makes sense, but the second one starts to break down and not make sense, not sure why.

> 1. I eventually quickly walked to the store.
> 2. I walked to the store eventually quickly.

While you can move the placement of adverbs like this, it appears that adjectives must always directly precede the noun (but maybe I'm wrong there, can't think of any examples):

> The **big red oak** tree fell down.

You could say "the oak tree that was big and red fell down", but to me that is starting to create a different kind of sentence. I dunno.

Do any languages allow for even less flexibility than English when it comes to adjectives/adverbs ("modifiers")? Placing them in a fixed position relative to the head noun/verb, and you can never vary from that? Or do all languages allow multiple ways of saying the same thing?

Comment: German word order is more flexible in some ways and less flexible than others.  For example, in German main clauses, the verb must always be in the second position.  So you can’t say “I quickly walked to the store.”   On the other hand, in German you can say “To the store walked I quickly.”

Comment: The reason #2 starts to break down is that _eventually_ is a sentence adverb – it modifies the entire utterance – whereas _quickly_ modifies the verb specifically. Sentence adverbs can be placed fairly freely, but not adverbs that modify individual elements.